# Calculating propagation of uncertainty

Tags: functional-analysis, statistics, derivatives, error-propagation

I need to compute the propagation of uncertainty $u(N')$.

It is known that $N' = \frac{N}{t}$ and:

- $u(N) = \sqrt{N}$
- $u(t) = 0.1$

My attempt at the task:
$$u(N') = \sqrt{\Bigg[ \frac{\partial N'}{\partial t} u(t) \Bigg]^2 + \Bigg[\frac{\partial N'}{\partial N} u(N)\Bigg]^2} = \sqrt{\Bigg[ -\frac{N}{t^2} u(t)\Bigg]^2 + \Bigg[\frac{1}{t} u(N)\Bigg]^2}$$

Does this look correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Errors can be computed that way, i.e. if $N'=N'(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ the uncertainty of $N'$, $u(N')$ is given by
$$
u(N')=\sqrt{\sum_k^n\Big((\partial_{x_k}N')u(x_k)\Big)^2}
$$
where $\partial_{x_k}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}$ is the partial derivative with respect to $x_k$.
It is easy to check that
$$
\frac{u(N')}{N'}=\sqrt{\sum_k^n\Big(\frac{u(x_k)}{x_k}\Big)^2}.
$$

Comment: I need to compute $u(N')$, not $u(N)$. I have used the formula:

$$u(N') = \sqrt{   \sum_{i=1}^{k} \Bigg[ \frac{\partial N'}{\partial x_{i}} u(x_{i}) \Bigg]^2}$$

Comment: @weno see my update